# How do I use one column to gate select rows of another column in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a column of 1's and 0's and another column with double values. I want to make a third column that contains the data in each of the rows in the second column that corresponds to a 1 in the first column. I have no idea how to do this and googling for this has been a nightmare. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi @Derpman500, Welcome to SO!  First, for your question, the more info you can provide and specifics the better. Can you show the data by doing ```dput(head(df,10))``` to show some of your data?  Also, if you can show what you want your expected output to look like that is also very helpful in aiding others inanswering your question.  You can use the ```edit``` link on the bottom left under your question to add this additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a one-liner with `ifelse`. Assuming your data frame is called `df`, 1 and 0 values in `col1`, doubles in `col2`, values corresponding to the zeros are `NA`:

```
df$col3 <- ifelse(df$col1, df$col2, NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` in a single-line using indexing.  We create the logical vector with first 'col1' and use that as index to create the new column.  By default, the values that are FALSE from 'i1' will be `NA`

```
i1 <- as.logical(df1$col1) 
# // or
# i1 <- df1$col1 == 1
df1$col3[i1] <- df1$col2[i1]
```

Or as a single line

```
df1$col3[as.logical(df1$col1)] <- df1$col2[as.logical(df1$col1)]
```